Plotting a function that is a function of another function
I am trying to plot the following graph for different values of t (t=1 to t=10) in one plot.
Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {0, 6}}]

When I use
 Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[1], 1]], {x, 0, x0[1]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {0, 6}}]

I get a correct output. However, when I use this in a for loop (as follows) I get no output.
For[t = 1, t < 10, t++, 
 Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {0, 6}}]]


Maybe wrap a Print around your Plot[...] Or try a[u_,v_]:=u^3;x0[t_]:=t^4; Table[ Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]],{x,0,x0[t]},PlotRange->{{0,14},{0,6}}],{t,1,10}] but we are just guessing what your a[u_,v_] and your x0[t] are

Thanks. These both work but show many graphs at output. Is there any way one could show them all in one graph with different colors for different values of t? @Bill

You can generate the plots using Table and combine them into one plot with Show.
You don't define the functions a and x0 in your question, so I use dummy definitions as an example:
a[y_, t_] := 2 y^2 + 2 t;
x0[t_] := t + 4;


plot = Show[
  Table[
    Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {0, 6}}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][t]], 
  {t,10}]
]

This gives

If you want to a legend showing the color of each t value, first create the legend:
legend = LineLegend @@ Transpose[Table[{ColorData[97][t], t}, {t, 10}]]

then combine it with the plot
Legended[plot, legend]


Is it possible to show what t value each color is related to?

yes, see my edit for how to add a legend

would it be possible to add the legend label "t" to the legend too?

yes. Check the documentation of LineLegend for ways to format the legend. The option LegendLabel adds a label.
